# Backbone.js collection view render multiple times for single trigger

Tags: backbone.js, listener, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

I have backbone.js collection and collectionview. collection view listening to its collection `add` event. But when I add new models to it's collection it renders mutiple times for each model.
Please Check the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rfzqtyru/7/)

```
var ImageCollectioView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    this.collection.bind('add', this.render, this);
  },

  collection: imgColection,
  el: '#cont',
  render: function() {
    var els = [], self = this;
    this.collection.each(function(image){
      var imageView = new ImageView({model: image});
      self.$el.append(imageView.render().el);
    });

    return this;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `render` method renders the entire collection. So after adding a model you should clear the existing item views:

```
 render: function() {
    var els = [], self = this;
    this.$el.empty();
    //------^---- clear existing
    this.collection.each(function(image){
      var imageView = new ImageView({model: image});
      self.$el.append(imageView.render().el);
    });

    return this;
}
```

That being said, it's better to add a separate method that just appends single item view rather than rendering the entire collection:

```js
var ImageCollectioView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.renderItem);
  },
  el: '#cont',
  render: function() {
    this.collection.each(this.renderItem, this);
    return this;
  },
  renderItem: function(image) {
    var imageView = new ImageView({
      model: image
    });
    this.$el.append(imageView.el);
  }
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rfzqtyru/11/)

Comment: I missed it, thanks, its working now, one more help does my backbone coding pattern is ok or its wrong?

Comment: @WimalWeerawansa Your coding is ok, though can be improved. See https://jsfiddle.net/rfzqtyru/10/. Main this is that you shouldn't hardcode model/collection instances inside view constructor. Either create them outside and pass them as options or create them inside views. Another thing is you don't have to manually initialize models

Comment: Again Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @WimalWeerawansa oh forgot to mention [`this.listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) instead of `bind`... helps to avoid memory leak.